# Improving Docker security

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am in the process of putting the final touches to a web application that allows users to run Docker sessions that host a variety of different applications.  As I review security one of the thoughts that has occurred to me is that users could bring the entire system - all hosted sessions for all users - to a grounding halt by simply writing too much data to the file system.

To avoid this one of the measures I have taken is to set up  virtual drive with limited space that is used to map (via Docker) folders that are liable to be accessed by the user.  The precise folders that get mapped depend on what is being hosted in the Docker container. For instance, when hosting a MySQL database I map the `/var/lib/mysql` folder to prevent the DB from growing in an uncontrolled manner.

So far so good - however, I realized just a few hours ago that another, universal, weak link is the `/tmp` folder.  So I tried mapping that folder to the virtual drive too.  Naively at first - owned by www-data and `chmod'd` to 775: which promptly brought everything to a halt.  I could not run containers with php5, mysql, memcached or indeed most things.

After poking around on my "real" server I changed the mapped `/tmp` folder to be owned by *root* and `chmod'd` it to 777 which had everything working again.

In the process I discovered something else:

- Docker uses the [AUFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) file system. So, for instance, a "normal" `/tmp` folder in a Docker session would be on AUFS.
- Not a problem you might say.  However, AUFS does not have all the same capabilities as, say, EXT4.
- To give just one example: I would like to use extended file system attributes `apt-get install attr` and then `setfattr -n...` on some of the files that go into my `/tmp` folder

**The neat thing** - if you map a volume Docker retains the file system of the folder that was mapped. Thus if I set up my virtual drive as EXT4 and map a folder on it to act as `/tmp` in a Docker session that `/tmp` folder inside the session would be EXT4.

However, all of this has thrown up more questions than it has answered

1. What are the precise risks entailed by allowing docker session users to write to disk in an uncontrolled manner?
2. Having discovered the AUFS vs EXT4 issue I googl'd and found [this](http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/09/30/overview-storage-scalability-docker/) as the first hit.  Sounds like just the place to go to understand all the issues involved but as you will see that link leads nowhere.
3. What are the *right ownership* and privs for the `'/tmp` folder?
4. Am I storing up other problems mapping `/tmp`, changing its owner and `chmod'ing` it?
5. Finally, are there other OS folders that could get abused and are worthy contenders for being mapped to a limited sized virtual drive?

I should also mention:

- All of these adventures are on a Ubuntu 14.10 setup.
- What happens when the virtual drive runs out of disk space? - I run a minutely CRON job that alerts the user when their disk space is running low.

I have learned a great deal about Docker and Linux over the past few months but I am far from being an expert. I'd be most obliged to anyone who might be able to fill in the gaps here and answer some of those questions.

Comment: I don't have precise answers to your question, because I'm still learning about these details myself, but I came to drop off something that I think may be helpful. Reading through the following document has helped educate me to the risks of running the docker daemon and its configuration as well as the host machine config: https://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/docker/CIS_Docker_1.11.0_Benchmark_v1.0.0.pdf Obviously application code should be vulnerability free too.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers of your posts;

1. It is one of the biggest problem of the Docker. But the common practice on these situation to form up a NAS Device (Network Attached Storage) and mount the container inside that drive, so that the host will cover it's uptime if the storage is full.
2. About this one, yes this is the issue of having a smaller overhead, because in the AUFS there is only layer system which is, "only save the changes". That's why you can experience these kinds of problems.
3. For `/tmp` the correct permissions will be Read+Write for everyone.
4. I cannot answer this question
5. Try not to connect the containers to the root volume that way you can prevent many things from the start. But always be careful with these folders;

   `/bin /tmp /boot /proc`